# JavaScript function called from Rails: not loading entire parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameters

this is my problem. From rails I call a function:

```
<body onload="initialize(<%= @segnalazione.id %>,<%= @segnalazione.dove %>); ">
```

where @segnalazione.dove is like "(lat, lng)".

On the called function, the map is not loaded because half cood is loaded. If I run "alert(coord);" I get only "lng". Why?

```
function initialize(id,coord) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: coord,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,draggableCursor:'pointer'
            }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step to debugging a problem like this is to see what the code that Rails is generating looks like, i.e. what HTML/JavaScript is actually being sent to the browser.

In this case I'm guessing the problem is you're not quoting strings. Your first line should probably look like this:

```
<body onload="initialize(<%= @segnalazione.id %>, '<%= @segnalazione.dove %>'); ">
```

(Note the new single-quotes around the `@segnalazione.dove` ERb tag. This is necessary if `@segnalazione.dove` is a string instead of, say, an integer or other JavaScript literal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on `<body onload="initialize(<%= @segnalazione.id %>,<%= @segnalazione.dove %>); ">` if `@segnalazione.dove` expands to `(lat, lng)` the comma operator inside the parentheses will make `(lat, lng)` evaluate to `lng`. You can't use "()" how you seen to use it, go for `{lat: lat, lng: lng}`(as an object) or `[lat, lng]`(as a array).